# Get class/type of model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there a way to get the class or type of a model? For example if my model was a "todo" and if I wanted to get that information from the record itself like:

```
todo = this.get('model');
todo.class
```

OR would it possible to get it from the 'content' of a controller? I think model is just an alias for content but I could be wrong. I figured there has to be a simple way to do this but I can't find anything after much googling. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

the constructor is probably what you're looking for, it's located on the proto of the object

```
`todo.constructor`
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/871/edit

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't seem to get the value. Is it something like this?:
todo = @get('model');
todo.constructor

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following:

```
type = @get('model').get('constructor.typeKey')
```

Thanks to kingpin2k for the help.